# MATLAB Image Mass and Inertia

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a piece of code, I am trying to understand. It is given by my colleague and I am struggling on why she employed the way she did. In comments she mentioned the variable inertai1 gives the uniformity factor. I was wondering how does this give uniformity of an image.

**Background of Code:** 
Initially it is a 2D image. The intensity values in every column is added and I got a 1D vector. Then all the values are divided by the maximum value in the 1D vector. Basically Normalizing.

If I is the image read. I has values from 0 to 255.

```
S = sum(I,2); Smax = max(S);
Cprofile = S/Smax;

I2 = I*10; 
I2(I2>255) = 255;
S2 = sum(I2,2); S2max = max(S2);
Cprofile2 = S2/S2max;
kCprofile2 = fft(Cprofile2); 
//Do some frequency manipulations
Cprofile2_f = ifft(kCprofile2)
```

inperpx is inch per pixel.

b1 and d1 are the first and last indices of Cprofile I am interested in.

```
 inertia1=0;
    mass1=0;

    for ii=b1:d1;
        mass1=mass1+inperpx*Cprofile(ii);
        inertia1=inertia1+abs(Cprofile2_f(ii)-Cprofile(ii))*inperpx;
    end

    inertia1=1-inertia1/mass1;
```

Comment: What are you triying to figure out?

Comment: Updated question: Trying to understand the physical meaning behind the code

Comment: What is the definition of `inperpx`, and `Cprofile2_f`?

Comment: You can leave out `inperpx` and not change the output.

Comment: @rayryeng added some code

Comment: "Do some frequency manipulations" is probably the relevant part! This looks to me like one of those "I did this and it seems to work, but I don't know why" kludges. There are several well-established ways of determining uniformity, this is not one of them. And inertia is definitely not defined that way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "Do some frequency manipulations" part you left out removes or reduces the high frequencies (i.e. applies a low-pass filter), then the loop there computes the sum of absolute differences between the input and the smoothed version. The sum of absolute differences is larger when there are more high frequency components in the image, and thus the image is less "uniform".

Note that same can be computed with `mass1=sum(Cprofile(b1:d1))` and a similar statement for `inertia1`. Multiplying by `inperpx` is useless, as that scales both values identically and then you divide the two, rendering the scaling meaningless.

Also note that the statement `I(I>255) = 255` can be removed, as you don't use `I` after. Maybe this was meant to be `I2(I2>255) = 255`?